Raspberry Pi 5: Host + Slave USB setup
Project:
Plug a USB mouse into a Raspberry Pi
Read the mouse inputs
Forward them to a PC (That PC recognises the Pi as a mouse device)
Background:
Hey Guys,
I'm currently struggling with trying to achieve this setup.
I've setup a HID device within the Pi 5, and it reads the mouse inputs (verified by displaying to console),
My PC makes a sound (standard device plugged in sound) when I setup the HID. But the movements go get forward to the PC.
To my knowledge the only port on thr Raspberry Pi 5 that can do Gadget Mode, is the USB C port. Now this is an issue, as the USB C port is needed for power. If you decide to plug the USB C into the PC for power + data. You get low voltage errors as not enough draw and the forwarded movements don't work.
Question:
Is there another way to achieve this?
Possible Fix:

USB Hub that can handle power and data?
POE+ Hat for Pi 5, which will free up the USB C port for data


A USB port is either a host or a device (peripheral). What is going on in the hardware and software of a USB host device is very different and much more complex from what is going on on the hardware and software of a USB device (peripheral). All normal RPi USB ports are Hosts. I am not aware of any RPi USB ports that can be converted into a device (peripheral). That said, I did read this:"4B and 400 can do USB host and USB device at the same time". So maybe you can do what you want on the right RPi.

@st2000 Some models (including the Zero, 4, and 5) can configured to use their power port in OTG/gadget (ie., slave, what you refer to as peripheral) mode, which the OP correctly stated in the question.

Interesting. Didn't know that. Well, if it's possible then you could cut open the USB between the RPi and PC. Cut the positive wire in half and tap into the ground wire (leaving the ground of the PC USB port connected to the ground of the RPi USB port. Then connect the positive wire from the RPi USB port to a appropriately sized power supply for the RPi you are using. Also, as you suggested, you might find a USB power hub that can do the same (allow PC USB data lines to connect to the RPi wile supplying an alternative source of power).
